# Access child struct values in vector

Tags: c++

I have some Object structs that look like this:

```
struct Object {
   string type;
   Color c;
   float ambient, diffuse;
};

struct Sphere: Object {
   Point center;
   float radius;
};

struct Square: Object {
   Point loc;
   float len;
};
```

And I have a vector that is filled with Sphere and Square structs:

```
vector<Object> objs;
Sphere sp = //sphere stuff
Square sq = //square stuff
objs.push_back(sp);
objs.push_back(sq);
```

I can access the values in the parent struct just fine, but I am having trouble figuring out how to access the values in the Sphere and Square structs. This is what I am doing right now:

```
cout << objs.at(i).type << endl; //This works
cout << objs.at(i).center.x << endl; //Not working
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: First [read about object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Then learn more about *pointers*. And finally about [upcasting and (more specifically) ***downcasting***](https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/upcasting-downcasting.htm) and how to use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). Then you should know how to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, they don't exist any more. You are not storing `Square`s or `Sphere`s in the `vector`, you are just storing `Object`s. You should read [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274634/1171191).

That said, if you were instead to store *pointers* to `Object`s, `std::vector<Object*>` you could pass pointers to the objects of the derived types. But then how would you know which element in the `vector` was a `Square` and which was a `Sphere`. The whole purpose of having a base class would be to provide an *interface* to the functionality you want, through a `virtual` function, which the derived classes *implement* in different ways:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "foo in base\n"; }
};
struct Derived1 : Base {
    void foo() override { std::cout << "foo in Derived1\n"; }
};
struct Derived2 : Base {
    void foo() override { std::cout << "foo in Derived2\n"; }
};

Derived2 d;
Base* b = &d;
b->foo(); // prints "foo in Derived2\n"
```

---

That said, to get a `Square*` from an `Object*`, use `static_cast<Square*>(objP)` if you know for sure it is a `Square`, and `dynamic_cast<Square*>(objP)` if you are not certain (it will return a null pointer if you are wrong). **Having to do this probably indicates a bad design though!**

---

Also, please reconsider your use of what are often considered bad practices: [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html) (those are links to explanations).

Comment: Good point, thanks! Clearly I avoid it so much I forgot how it works.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<T&>` will throw upon error, though :)

Comment: @Quentin My above comment was a response to (since removed) Some Programmer Guy pointing out that it returns null for pointers, throws for references. I had originally incorrectly said that it will throw.

Comment: I haven't seen that comment, just wanted to complete it in case it had gone just "Nope, `dynamic_cast<T*>` returns `nullptr`" without mentioning the reference case.